# Limit my description field to 300 words

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I've got the following snippet of code and its all working, and bringing in the data I want, but its bringing in too much data for my search result. I would like to break it down to 300 words. I have found the code I need to attach to the description field, but I am uncertain of how to do this. The code I believe will take the first 300 words is

`Split(' ').Take(300).Aggregate((a, b) => a + " " + b);`

The linq code I am using is below:

```
    searchResults.DataSource = from r in response.Results
                               select new
                               {
                                   Title = r[SearchContentProperty.Title],
                                   Summary = r[SearchContentProperty.HighlightedSummary],
                                   Id = r[SearchContentProperty.Id] * 10,
                                   Quicklink = r[SearchContentProperty.QuickLink],
                                   Description = r[SearchContentProperty.Description]
                               };
```

Comment: Can you provide some more code? I just don't understand this right, is this your code or are you going to use this?

Comment: Hi Guys, sorted underneath, I wanted to reduce the description field word count to 300.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
searchResults.DataSource = from r in response.Results
                           select new
                           {
                               Title = r[SearchContentProperty.Title],
                               Summary = r[SearchContentProperty.HighlightedSummary],
                               Id = r[SearchContentProperty.Id] * 10,
                               Quicklink = r[SearchContentProperty.QuickLink],
                               Description = r[SearchContentProperty.Description].ToString().Split(' ').Take(300).Aggregate((a, b) => a + " " + b);
                           };
```

Comment: Ah perfect, I tried that but without the ToString() - so my version failed. Thank you